# How do I remove all corporate settings from Windows?

Tags: security, domain, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 Enterprise PC that formerly belonged to a corporate domain network, with some settings configured by the IT department. The company discarded the PC and allowed me to take personal ownership of it, but some of the corporate settings are still active. How can I remove all of their settings without doing a clean wipe and reinstall of Windows?

Here's an example of one setting, but I don't want to chase them down one by one, because I don't even know what they all are. Windows Security->Firewall & Network Protection->Private Network->Microsoft Defender Firewall: it's disabled with the message "This setting is managed by your administrator."

I tried the "Command Prompt" method from [this page](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-local-group-policy-objects-their-default-settings-windows-10) but it didn't help.

**Edit:** I would like to avoid deleting all of the installed software. "Reset this PC" would wipe everything.

Comment: **How can I remove all of their settings without doing a clean wipe and reinstall of Windows?** - Go to Settings>Update & Security>Recovery>Reset this PC>Remove everything. This will "reset" Windows 10 as if it were a clean install without actually having to reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: The first step would be to disjoin the computer from the domain/active directory. That will keep the applications but all domain user accounts will not work afterwards. Make sure you have a local administrator account ready before leaving the domain.

Comment: The reason the "command prompt" method didn't work is that not all policies are applied via Group Policy and the registry any longer. Depending on how the computer was enrolled, you may have Intune, Desired State Configuration, Windows boot and login scripts, and other methods of control. The correct method is that your own should wiped the device before giving it to you, and you should do that now. Otherwise you're going to be playing a game of whack-a-mole.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to [sysprep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--system-preparation--overview) the system, it is not designed for this exact purpose but performs some similar tasks.

Removes PC-specific information from the Windows image, including the PC’s security identifier (SID). This allows you to capture the image and apply it to other PCs. This is known as generalizing the PC.

Uninstalls PC-specific drivers from the Windows image.

Prepares the PC for delivery to a customer by setting the PC to boot to OOBE.

Sysprep can also be configured to retain installed drivers via editing registry keys:

```
Move to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep\Settings\sppnp
Select Edit - New DWORD value
Enter a name of PersistAllDeviceInstalls
Set to a value of 1 and click OK
```

Comment: This would also remove the programs the author has installed.

Comment: Isn't the whole purpose of sysprep to strip out machine identifiers and retain installed software? I could see certain applications that are licensed to the system id requiring re-activation, but not being removed

Comment: You should read up on the process.

Comment: You should read up on the process. – Ramhound 1 min ago

I just looked and found this:
https://serverfault.com/a/450127